# What does a Linux distro need to act as a router?

Tags: ubuntu, router, fedora, routing

Im trying to setup a one of my machines with preferably ubuntu/fedora since I will be running some services on it.

So it would have to do:

- DHCP
- Port forwarding
- Firewalling

Am I missing services?

And can anyone suggest packages that can handle this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question several months ago over on SF: [linux router setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/133405/linux-router-setup/133414#133414).

Answer (score 1):

well, for dhcp - you need to install dhcpd (dhcp3-server).

iptables are basically a given in most linux distros (port forwarding and firewalling).

For details https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: +1 For iptables and dhcpd, they're all you need for a basic firewall/router.  iptables can be configured for port forwarding as well as firewalling and routing and there are even some script generators on the internet to set up iptables for you.  http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=aZJ&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&q=iptables+setup+script+generator&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: How about for wireless? just HostAP?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [ShoreWall](http://www.shorewall.net/) to abstract IPTables and ease the process. [This guide](http://www.shorewall.net/two-interface.htm) may be of help.